# Utility network trace using Quickgraph

Tags: quickgraph

I plan to use quickgraph for Utility network(directed graph with source sink node) with some concept:

```
Tracing Upstream: tracing all the edges whose flow directions are towards the node under the flow direction with one node as the beginning to upstream.

Tracing Downstream: tracing all the edges whose flow directions are towards the node under the flow direction with one node as the beginning to downstream.

Source: it is a node at the head of upstream, like valve in water net.

Sink: it is a node at the bottom of downstream, like the outlet in water supplying network.

Barrie: it is a stop node, like outage on pile in water net

Disable node: it is a stop node like closer with open status in electric net
```

So In Quickgraph

```
- is there algorithm for Tracing Upstream, Tracing Downstream?

- is there concept barrie, disable node?
```

Thanks in advance